# Is it possible to create a diffuse effect on a 2d mesh in opengl?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es

In the picture below I have a 2d mesh represented by the white square. (the rounded corners are all mesh geometry) As you can see the square has a bit of shading around it's edges. That is what I want to accomplish, a shader which adds a diffuse effect whenever it is near an edge. Is it possible to do this in opengl? Normally you use normals calculated from angles of faces, but this has to be a 2d mesh so that route is not possible. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There a many ways to accomplish this in GL, the graphics pipeline is quite flexible.

One possibility: add a new vertex data stream, which contains the distance of the vertex from the closest edge. That data would be passed to the fragment shader from the vertex shader, and used to darken the fragment, if it is close enough to the edge.